# Loading nib file for universal application

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nib

I an universal application how to create and load a nib file programmatically? How to connect the objects outlet in the new nib file? Or every time i have to check whether the device is iPhone or iPad and accordingly place the objects?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create separate xib for iPhone and iPad, like- ViewA, ViewA~iPad and you have to load conditionally-

```
ViewA *myView;
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
     myView = [[ViewA alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewA" bundle:nil];
}
else {
    myView = [[ViewA alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewA~iPad" bundle:nil];
}
```

If you want to create some view programatically, then you have to deal with their frames using the same if-else conditions.

Comment: Thanks but how to connect objects of these two xib to the outlet in the view controller?

Comment: viewA and ViewAiPad are UIView or UIViewController?

Comment: If both xib have some common outlet, suppose uilabel is present on both xib, then you need to create a IBOutlet and connect same outlet to both xib. As at a time only one will be loaded, so that will be taken care.

Comment: Currently i have taken an example of view controller, but that can be anything. You won't need to worry about that. To be simple in words -  currently where you are using single xib, you just need to have one more xib and this condition while loading xib. Rest things are done like they are done in iPhone or iPad app.